# How to provide SSL/TLS based communication on Mosquitto?

Tags: ssl, openssl, mosquitto

I am working on an app that uses Mqtt protocol to communicate with nodes. I use Mosquitto as a broker on Windows. I want to use SSL/TLS feature of Mosquitto to provide secure authentication and messaging mechanism. I create related certificates and make configuration on mosquitto.conf file. However, when I try to load mosquitto.conf from command prompt and restart mosquitto service, the service cannot be started and give an error. I'll explain what I did;

1) I created certificates by using OpenSSL. I followed instructions on "https://eclipse.org/mosquitto/man/mosquitto-tls-7.php".
First, I created ca.crt (the root CA certificate);
[image]

Related certificate information is shown above. I also entered "trialca" as PEM password for ca.crt. Then, I created server.key (i use "trialsrv" as a password), server.csr and server.crt;
[image];
[image]

2) I made some configuration on mosquitto.conf;

```
cafile /demo/ca.crt

certfile /demo/server.crt

keyfile /server.key

require_certificate true

use_identity_as_username true
```

Note: I use default listener on port 1883.

3) I load mosquitto.conf from command prompt on Mosquitto server running on PC.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto> mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
```

Then, I restarted Mosquitto service from Services on Windows. However, it could not be started and gave an error.
[image]

Is there anything I made wrong? I need your recommendations to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue this afternoon. I resolved it by stripping out the password in the server key. The command line exe didn't need a pw and the service started up without that error.

After generating the certs, run this. (rename the server.key to server.key.org first)

```
openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
```

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/can-i-skip-the-pem-pass-phrase-question-when-i-restart-the-webserver

Comment: Actually, removing password may not be a right solution, but it makes me move on. thank u very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you've already started one instance of mosquitto from the command line, then starting it as a service won't work because the first one is already running with the same config.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but there were something different in the problem. I've solved it, thank u.